# How to draw this SIR model in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hi, I have tried for hours without results. How to draw this in overleaf? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. If you tried for hours, perhaps you could edit your question to add a document showing what you've tried and we'll help you with the parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: For now I have only done this. Can't do the line over boxes and the \lamda on arrow.

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=20mm},
]
%Nodes
\node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {S};
\node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=of maintopic] {I};
\node[squarednode]      (lowercircle)       [right=of rightsquare] {R};

%Lines
\draw[thick,->] (maintopic.east) -- (rightsquare.west);
\draw[thick,->] (rightsquare.east) -- (lowercircle.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Comment: Btw. just for the future to avoid confusion, Overleaf is just an online editor with tex/latex backend. You can plot these things and embed in latex natively with Tikz, pdftricks, metapost and others. Looks like you want to use tikz, which seems like an appropriate choice to me.

Comment: @Please replace parts of your code (also add `calc` and `arrows` to `usetikzlibrary`): At the start:  `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\horsize}{20mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=\horsize}, ]` and everything below  `%Lines` with this: `\draw[thick,->] (maintopic.east) --node[pos=0.5,above,name=middle]{$\lambda$} (rightsquare.west);
\draw[thick,->] (rightsquare.east) -- (lowercircle.west);
\draw[thick,dashed,-latex] ($(middle)+({\horsize/(2*sqrt(2))},{\horsize/(1.9*sqrt(2))})$)  arc(45:135:\horsize/2);`. You can take it from there...

Comment: Thank you very much.